# Is there a way to change the Azure function trigger type programmatically.

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Looks like function.json in your Azure function's zip file defines Az func's trigger. Is it possible to change the trigger from Timer based to Event based programatically? Meaning, can I have a python application running perhaps in my local computer which calls Azure python sdk and says hey, change the Azure Function x's trigger from timer based to event hub based trigger and here is the additional event hub namespace name and connection string information that you need.

Comment: Your app would have to redeploy the Function App with updated `function.json`. By the way Event Hub trigger has different input (event content), so I guess the function body would have to change too.

Comment: @Mikhail...That makes sense..thats the alternative i thought it would be

Comment: at the end, did you find my answer useful?

Comment: @Vladislav I did not try your answer. I worked around with what suggested.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.
However, I can think of the following workaround, which should accomplish the goal.

First, you can define multiple function triggers within one function project (one function app service). They could be bound to different targets. Something like this:

```
public static class Functions
{
    [FunctionName("FunctionTimer")]
    public static async Task RunAsync([TimerTrigger("%Schedule%")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
        if (!AppSettings.IsTimerTriggerActive) 
            return;
        ...
    }

    [FunctionName("FunctionEventHub")]
    public static async Task RunAsync([EventHubTrigger("", Connection = "eventHubConnectionString")] EventData[] eventDataBatch, ILogger log)
    {
        if (!AppSettings.IsEventHubTriggerActive) 
            return;
        ...
    }
}
```

You cannot enable/disable a function programmatically, but you can control which one of these is active via the App Service Application Settings. The latter could be managed through the Web App API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/updateapplicationsettings

Thus you can activate either trigger. One can even skip the (de)activation if that's compatible with the logic.

Comment: @Vladislav..I am using node.js to do it, i believe this is C# or Java.. can you please write the similar snippet in node.js if you know node.js?..thanks!!...

Comment: Not sure if node.js is supported - according to the current documentation - it is not (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/supported-languages). The snippet is pretty general, nothing specific.

Comment: I basically meant Javascript in that case.

Comment: Can you please explain the %Schedule% part, where and how do you define it?

Comment: Hi, `%Schedule%` is an app setting key name. These are defined in the `Values` object in local.settings.json and respectively in Application Settings on he function in Azure Portal. [Details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#settings)

Comment: Just checking two years later: Is it yet possible to change a Function's trigger by overwriting the values in `function.json`?

Comment: No, as far as I know.