# In azure function app, how to manually change function app trigger type after creation?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

So, I have a function app with http trigger, with the following settings

function.json

```json
{
  "bindings": [{
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    }, {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, I want to change the trigger type to queue, I updated the settings as such:

```json
{
  "type": "queueTrigger",
  "direction": "in",
  "name": "queueItem",
  "queueName": "adreporterqueue",
  "connection": "QueueConnectionString"
}
```

I published the function. But the trigger type is still http. How to change it to queue manually not programmatically unlike this question ([Is there a way to change the Azure function trigger type programmatically.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50939889/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-azure-function-trigger-type-programmatically))?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to change the Azure function trigger type programmatically.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50939889/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-azure-function-trigger-type-programmatically)

Comment: Unfortunately no, that question is quite different from mine. I want to change the trigger type manually not programmatically (which is not possible).

Comment: did you delete the existing files?

Comment: no, I only changed the settings according to this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=javascript#configuration

Comment: before publishing you need to delete the existing files, this can be done if you are using visual studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid that will not be possible.

However, this has been already discussed here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/437094/index.html

[to avoid duplication]

Comment: yeah I created a new function with queue trigger, thanks anyway.